# Local Mandatory Profile doesn't work after joining a domain

Tags: windows, windows-10, domain, user-profiles, local

In our training environment we want to run several laptops with temporary profiles. This means that all changes should be deleted after the shutdown. Therefore we use a Mandatory Profile.

The Mandatory Profile should be a local login and the clients should also be in a domain because of GPO (domain users no choice, because the laptops do not have a permanent network).  But as soon as I join the domain the Mandatory profile is a normal user profile and saves everything. 
If I leave the domain, it works fine again.
It's not the GPO, it has been completely deactivated for testing purposes.

Any tips?

Operating System is a  Windows 10.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "local login" and by "joining the domain". You can either login through a DC-account or through a account on the local machine, not both at the "same time" (unless you login twice).

Comment: I mean the machine is in a domain and managed by a dc server (GPO), but the main account used to work on the clients is a local profile. And this local profile is a mandatory profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to setup the mandatory profile to be on a server share in the domain as that's the way that functionality works with Windows in domain environments so it's likely the way you have it configured that needs to change but I've done this successfully many times in the past.

> ### [How to apply a mandatory user profile to users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mandatory-user-profile)
>
> In a domain, you modify properties for the user account to point to
>   the mandatory profile in a shared folder residing on the server.
>
> **To apply a mandatory user profile to users**
>
> Open **Active Directory Users and Computers** (`dsa.msc`).
>
> Navigate to the user account that you will assign the mandatory
>   profile to.
>
> Right-click the user name and open **Properties**.
>
> On the **Profile** tab, in the **Profile** path field, enter the path
>   to the shared folder without the extension. For example, if the folder
>   name is `\\server\profile.v6`, you would enter `\\server\profile`.
>
> Click **OK**.
>
> It may take some time for this change to replicate to all domain
>   controllers.
>
> [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mandatory-user-profile)

---

### Further Resources

- [Creating a mandatory profile on Windows 10 1803](https://james-rankin.com/articles/creating-a-mandatory-profile-on-windows-10-1803/)

  > **Windows 10 1607/1703/1709/1803**
  >
  > - Profile folder in AD or GPO – `\\SERVER\SHARE\PROFILE`
  > - Actual mandatory profile folder – `\\SERVER\SHARE\PROFILE.v6`
  > - Actual super-mandatory profile folder – `\\SERVER\SHARE\PROFILE.man.v6`
- [Roaming user profiles of earlier versions of Windows are incompatible with Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3056198/roaming-user-profiles-versioning-in-windows-10-and-windows-server)

Comment: Is there no possibility to save the profile on the computers, to use a local user and no AD-user?

I created an AD user, specified the profile path, shared the profile folder, but it never loads the mandatory profile. It always logs in with a local profile folder. Access properties of the share are definitely suitable and no GPO prevents share access.

Error log therefore does not return an error message.

Comment: First of all many, many thanks for your help! 

That it's easy I think to myself, my predecessor has set it up several times here in the house and I had copied it one to one. 
So the UNC path and this tab "Remote Desktop Services Profile" must be entered or do I misunderstand? Had it previously been entered under the tab "Profile" under "User profile".

Comment: That is correct, for the way I have it setup and working is to use the `Remote Desktop Services Profile` tab of the AD user account and then in the `Profile Path` in there you will set it up to point to the UNC path of the `profile.v6` named man profile. I'll have to see if I can setup a test for a local man profile on one of the domain environments I support to see about that though still. I'm curious to know if that location will resolve the AD account man profile issue though when you get to it.